# How to set RadTextBox name attribute as static to use in Javascript

Tags: asp.net, .net, telerik, jquery-validate, radtextbox

I am using telerik  `RadTextBox` inside `asp.net` User Control page.

I have writen below `Jquery` validation code inside main content page as shown below, I am trying to set RadText box `name` attribute as static inside User Control so that I can use it in Main Content page.

**User Control page**

```
<telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtProductPrice" ClientID="txtProductPrice" 
runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

**Main Content Page:**

```
    $("#aspnetForm").validate({
        rules: {
            ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ucUserInfoI$txtProductPrice: {
                required: true,
                number: true,
                maxlength: 5            
            },
        }
    });
```

I have used dynamically generated name attribute to validate the textbox, which looks ugly.

Since RadTexBox is in UserControl page , I am not able to use RadTexBox with `UniqueID` in main content page as below:

```
  $("#aspnetForm").validate({
        rules: {
            <%=txtProductPrice.UniqueID %>:{
                required: true,
                number: true,
                maxlength: 5
            },
        }
    });
```

Any idea how to I can use RadTexBox with `UniqueID` in main content page ?

Any help would be great.

Comment: Unobtrusive Validation enabled?

Comment: *"So Is there any neat and shorter way to use name attribute inside Main Content page"* ~ What are you asking?  The plugin's parameter **MUST** match the actual rendered `name` attribute.  If the `name` attribute is not neat and short, then you need blame ASP.

Answer (score 1):

These steps can prove helpful to you:

**1.** For client-side logic, you can try using `<%=txtProductPrice.ClientID %>` instead of UniqueID.

**2.** Telerik controls are complex server and script controls and you should not use ClientIDMode="Static" with them. [Details](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/general-information/troubleshooting/general-troubleshooting#setting-clientidmode-property-to-static-breaks-the-telerik-controls-functionality)

**3.** Make sure you have the following setting in your web.config file as suggested by [Sparky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55406578/how-to-set-radtextbox-name-attribute-as-static-to-use-in-javascript#comment97535319_55406578):

```
<appSettings> 
<add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None"/>
```

Here are some [Details](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/general-information/troubleshooting/jquery-troubleshooting) and [More Details](https://www.telerik.com/forums/asp-net-4-5-unobtrusive-validation-and-radcontrols-for-asp-net-ajax).

**4.** You can always use the `$telerik.findControl` method to manually access the RadTextBox and execute your custom logic. [Details](https://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/details/access-telerik-controls-on-client-side)